# GAM model: Group-specific smoothers with different wiggliness of two random and nested factors

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I aim to model the specific seasonal population fluctuations of several species. In particular, I have the abundance of individual along several years of 20 populations belonging to 5 species, and I want to extract the specific seasonality of each population, but controlling by species. **I am especially interested in not modelling any global smoother neither for the seasonality nor the species**.

To this end, I though in performing a GAM model where (i) the population abundance is the dependent variable, (ii) the week of the year is the explanatory variable, and (iii) the population and species are two random and nested factors. Because of I want to apply a specific smoother per population and species, I though in performing what Pedersen et al. (2019) called a model "I".

In a very didactic way, Pedersen et al. (2019) showed the R code for the R package *mgcv* to apply a group-specific smoother of the Week variable for each

```
modSeasonal <- gam(Abundance ~ s(Weeks, by=Population, bs="cc", k=10, m=2) +
                               s(Population, bs="re", k=18)
```

bs="cc" is because of Week is a circular variable.

Later, basing on an answer of a question in StackExchange ([Random effect in GAM (mgcv package)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331692/random-effect-in-gam-mgcv-package)), I also included one smoother for each species is:

```
modSeasonal <- gam(Abundance ~ s(Weeks, by=Population, bs="cc", k=10, m=2) +
                               s(Population, bs="re", k=18) +
                               s(Population, bs="re", by=Species)
```

Could you please tell me if my specifications can rightly extract the seasonality of each population by controlling per species, without considering any global smoother? or should I indicate something in id?

**Reference**:

Pedersen, E. J., Miller, D. L., Simpson, G. L., & Ross, N. (2019). Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: an introduction with mgcv. PeerJ, 7, e6876.

Comment: Can you clarify what you *do* want; you say you don't want a global smoother, but then fit a model that includes one?

Comment: Excuse me, the R code was wrong. I want to specify a group-level smoother with differing wiggliness for the random effect “Species”. 
Similarly to the code related with the "Weeks" and "Populations" (specifications of the model I provided by Pedersen et al. 2019), I would like to specify that "Populations" of the same "Species" have the same wiggliness but without any restriction to be similar to those populations of other species. What could be considered as the specifications of the model I but for random nested effects.

Comment: You talk about wiggliness with respect to the random effects, which is confusing me; are you referring to the `s(Population, bs="re", by=Species)` term? If you include `Species` as a fixed factor, then that `by = Species` random effect can potentially have different shrinkage of the Populations to the individual Species averages. I don't think you need the first `Population` random effect. Are `Population`s unique within `Species` or not? That might complicate the first term. If `Week` is week of the year, then consider using `knots` to specify endpoints: `knots = list(Weeks = (0.5, 53.5))`

Comment: (1) Yes, I meant `s(Population, bs="re", by Species)`. However, I would like to consider `Species `as a random factor because I have a small proportion of the species I am interested in. Can I nest two random effects? (2) With respect to the first random effect of Population, I suppose you are referring to the `s(Population, bs="re", k=18)` term. I used it following the specifications provided by Pedersen et al. (2019; model CO2_modI). Is there a difference when it is included or not included?

Comment: (3) Thank you for commenting on the knots.  In my real model I had already included them as `knots = list (Weeks = (0,53)`). Is there any advantage when using non-real values such as 0.5,53.5? (4) Regarding my populations, yes, they are unique within the species. Should I indicate other specifications in the model?